# \$m \times n\$ grid of resistors, power dissipated through each is \$P_{total}/ (m \times n)\$

Tags: circuit-analysis

\$m \times n\$ grid of resistors (all of which are the same), power dissipated through each is \$P_{total}/ (m \times n)\$ ?

I just want to confirm my thinking: If the power is \$ P = IV \$ the current through each resistor will be \$ I / n \$ since there are n columns and the voltage will be \$V/ m\$ making the power through each \$IV/ nm\$. Multiplying this by the number resistors gives me back the original power.

Comment: Do you have a grid, or columns?  Your question indicates both at different times.

Comment: sorry, the wire would split into n different columns, each strain having m resistors.

Comment: so there are no horizontal resistors, only vertical (series in each column, then connection with zero resistance between all columns at top and bottom)?

Comment: Because "grid of resistors" usually means this: https://www.mbeckler.org/resistor_grid/

Comment: I would add the word "uniform" as in a uniform grid of resistors. If you wired some columns in series and other columns all in parallel you could get different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Any other result would violate conservation of energy.